# .Net core JWT authentication

Tags: .net-core, jwt

```
internal static IServiceCollection AddAuthServerAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.Authority = "https://localhost:44360";
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
            };
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(o =>
        {
            o.AddPolicy("user", policy =>
            {
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes = new List<string>() { JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme };
                policy.RequireClaim("scope", "user");
            });
        });

        return services;
    }
```

The above code is to setup the JWT authentication for web api. When I run above api, I noticed below issue.

1. When both Auth server and api running, I fire the api via postman with valid token, the postman will return the expected result, which is normal.
2. But when I turn off the Auth server, and fire the api again, it still get the result. The result that I expected is it should show status code 500 or some error message due to the Auth server isn't running.
3. I need to restart the api again, and fire the api again, then only will get the error message because of the Auth server down.

Am I missed out any setting in Auth server/api layer?